# ARM binary(exetuable) compression

Tags: algorithm, arm, compression, executable

What is the best algorithm or way for compression ARM binary (executable) file?
Currently i tried a lot of algorithm and it looks that LZMA with filters is the best. But it works too long, so maybe there is another one good algorithm for this type of files?
Also maybe there is some another good filter for ARM binary (executable) compression like BCJ filter?
Maybe U can recommened some another preprocess techniques for my case?

Comment: Take a look at http://upx.sourceforge.net/. You may benchmark the algorithms (that UPX supports) without writing any code...

Answer (score 4):

If you want to have not so bad comprassion ratio and fast decompression try LZ4, it is designed this trade off in mind.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZ4_%28compression_algorithm%29):

> The algorithm gives a slightly worse compression ratio than the LZO
>   algorithm – which in turn is worse than algorithms like gzip. However,
>   compression speeds are similar to LZO, and several times faster than
>   other algorithms while decompression speeds can be up to three times
>   that of LZO. In a worst-case scenario, incompressible data gets
>   increased by 0.4%.

From its [LZ4](https://code.google.com/p/lz4/) page:

> a very fast lossless compression algorithm, providing compression
>   speed at 400 MB/s per core, scalable with multi-cores CPU. It also
>   features an extremely fast decoder, with speed in multiple GB/s per
>   core, typically reaching RAM speed limits on multi-core systems.

LZ4 [is included](https://lkml.org/lkml/2013/1/26/10) in Linux (kernel) as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have used lzfx, but the compression was done elsewhere and the embedded system only had to decompress.  somewhere on stack overflow this question was asked and answered with respect to minimal resources consumed and there were a number of favorites, all looked interesting.

Comment: Thank U for your answer. Do U remember what was that question? I can not find at stack overflow something like this. Btw, I looked at lzfx and it looks that he is fast, but with bad compression ratio. I will try him today, but i want such algorithm that will be with compression ratio like in lzma ( or better) and not so bad by decompression time like lzma.